# X-Twilio-Error: 20101 Invalid Access Token

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I am working with video feature with twilio. I have code like this,

File **index.php**

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); 
use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VideoGrant;

// Substitute your Twilio AccountSid and ApiKey details
$accountSid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$apiKeySid = 'SKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$apiKeySecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$identity = 'chatroom';

// Create an Access Token
$token = new AccessToken(
    $accountSid,
    $apiKeySid,
    $apiKeySecret,
    3600,
    $identity
);

// Grant access to Video
$grant1 = new VideoGrant();
$grant1->setRoom('php');
$token->addGrant($grant1);

// Serialize the token as a JWT
echo $token->toJWT();
```

With this, I am getting access token and I am using this with below code:

**local.js**

```
var accessToken = 'token';
var accessManager = Twilio.AccessManager(accessToken);
//console.log(accessManager);
var client = Twilio.Conversations.Client(accessManager);

// Begin listening for invites to Twilio Video conversations.
client.listen().then(function() {
  client.on('invite', function(invite) {
    invite.accept().then(onInviteAccepted);
  });
});
```

But I am getting error like this

```
SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
CSeq: 81 REGISTER
Call-ID: pgilp7ph926lumbhvn9
From: <sip:chatroom@ACac8904e851929e0f1e5f39457540d.endpoint.twilio.com>;tag=77troiv7s5
To: <sip:chatroom@ACac8904e851929e0f1e5f39457540d.endpoint.twilio.com>;tag=12029129_f28f532c_80fa4-ec12-4818-8a18-f4a4fe766
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 127.0.0.1:49162;branch=z9hG4bK877168;rport=49162
Server: Twilio
X-Twilio-Error: 20101 Invalid Access Token
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly You need to make sure that your API key, Secret key and account SID are correct.
Secondly , The error suggests that your key generated using above three data points is not correct/accepted by Twilio .
To check if the token is structurally correct visit [here](https://jwt.io/).